Is asking for pointers to already existing code on-topic for Stack Overflow?
I'm trying to understand how and where a library implements a specific functionality on Stack Overflow. I'm a beginner in that language and got stuck at tracing back the flow of control based on the code.
Stack Overflow is primarily for asking programming-related problems. Is it on-topic for Stack Overflow to ask "how did they do this and where can I find the code" or is there a better place to ask this question?

It sounds like your question is "where is the code in library L that does X?".  I don't know whether that is considered on-topic for Stack Overflow by the majority of users.  My opinion: It sounds to me like it could be acceptable, if it is narrowly scoped enough.
"How do I do X?" is also an acceptable question, if you have specified the problem clearly enough (the requirements and criteria for evaluating proposed answers are clear to all) and done sufficient research.  But this is different.
"What library should I use to do X?" is not an acceptable question here.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, Why was my "shopping list" question closed?, and What exactly is a recommendation question? for more explanations of why and further elaboration.
I know the latter two might sound like an unimportant distinction, but we have found that it is a useful distinction to draw, based on past experience with these types of questions.
If you are asking, please be very clear about which you are asking.  In your communication so far there has been some confusion about which of these you are intending.  Giving the backstory that you were wondering how to do X seems to just cause confusion; I would suggest omitting that.  Instead, ask where is the code in the library that does X.  Show your research so far and what progress you've made in tracking the control flow.  Make sure that you have scoped X narrowly and are asking about only one thing.
Just saying "serialize and de-serialize HTTP request and response objects from the Rust library http" is most likely not a detailed enough problem specification.  As the comments indicate, people are not finding it clear exactly what you're trying to achieve and what are the criteria for an answer to count as acceptable.  Also, that is asking about two separate functionality, so should be asked in two separate questions.
Beware that if you ask "How do I do X?", answers might not be in the form of a library recommendation.  One perfectly acceptable answer is to say "use API Y in library L", but another perfectly acceptable answer is a short snippet of code showing how to achieve it (without a special library).

My question is more about "How did they do X and where can I find this logic in their open-source code base?"

@Green绿色, I see. That wasn't clear to me. I don't know whether that is on-topic on SO. However, I have doubts about whether it is a good fit for the mission of SO.  The purpose of SO is to create a place where people can collaborate to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others. It's compiled in the form of questions (that others are likely to have) and answers. I'm not sure that the question "Where in the Rust http library is the code to serialize and deserialize requests?" is a question anyone else will have in the future, so I'm not sure whether it will be well-received.

Apparently not. And this question apparently wasn't well received either.

@Green绿色, It might be best to edit the question based on your latest clarifications.  What you want didn't come through based on the text of the question itself; it's only evident from the comments.

Ok, I edited my question. Hope, it's gotten clearer now.

@Green绿色: I don't know how familiar you are with Meta, but votes work a little differently here. You might get downvoted for poor research or confused/bad wording, but they can also indicate disagreement, i.e. a 'no' to your initial question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta for details

@AkselA isn't expressing disagreement by down voting contra productive? So, in the future, I'd better just avoid posting questions here...

@Green绿色: No, not at all, I'm just saying Meta is little different. One thing that is a little different is that down-votes have less "weight", because they're easier to give, because they have no cost, unlike on Main. So, don't worry too much.

Oh, I see. Apparently, this post hasn't influenced my reputation negatively.
